# How to auto login after registration

Tags: php, mysql

Like title says I want to log a user in once they successfully registered and don't want them to put username and password again to log in.

Here is registration code

```
<?php 
  $name = ((isset($_POST['name']))?sanitize($_POST['name']):'');
  $email = ((isset($_POST['email']))?sanitize($_POST['email']):'');
  $password = ((isset($_POST['password']))?sanitize($_POST['password']):'');
  $confirm = ((isset($_POST['confirm']))?sanitize($_POST['confirm']):'');
  $errors = array();
  if($_POST){
    $emailQuery =$db->query("SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE email = '$email'");
    $emailCount = mysqli_num_rows($emailQuery);

        if($emailCount != 0){
          $errors[] = 'That email already exists in our database.';
        }


    $required = array('name', 'email', 'password', 'confirm');
    foreach($required as $f){
      if(empty($_POST[$f])){
        $errors[] = 'You must fill out all fields';
        break;
      }
    }
    if(strlen($password) < 6){
      $errors[] = 'Your password must be atleast 6 characterss';
    }
    if($password != $confirm){
      $errors[] = 'Your password do not match';
    }
    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      $errors[] = 'You must enter a valid email';
    }
    if(!empty($errors)){
      echo display_errors($errors);
    }else{
      //add user to database
    $hashed = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
      $db->query("INSERT INTO users1 (full_name,email,password) values('$name', '$email','$hashed')");

  }
?>
```

And here is how my login structure looks like

```
<?php
 if ($_POST) {
    //form validation
    if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You must provide email and password.';
    }

    //Validate email
    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $errors[] = 'You must enter a valid email';
    }

    //Password is more than 6 characters
    if(strlen($password) < 6) {
        $errors[] = 'Password must be at least 6 characters';
    }

    // check if email exits in the database
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $usercount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($usercount < 1){
        $errors[] = 'That email does not exist in our database';
    }

    if (!password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
        $errors[] = 'The password does not match our records. Please try again.';
    }

    //check for errors
    if(!empty($errors)) {
        echo display_errors($errors);
    }else {
        $user_id = $user['id'];
      login($user_id);
    }
 }
?>
```

And here is login function

```
function login($user_id){
    $_SESSION['SBUser'] = $user_id;
    global $db;
    $date = date("y-m-d h:i:s");
    $db->query("UPDATE users SET last_login = '$date' WHERE id = '$user_id'");
    $_SESSION['success_flash'] = 'You are now logged in!';
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need for a login at all here. Think! The only thing that requires a login is you saying the user has to authenticate before you create a session for him. No one keeps you from generating such a session right after the registration. That done the user _is already_ logged in...

Comment: @arkascha Thats pretty much what I said to this question the last time he asked it, earlier today

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry, can't see that previous question.

Comment: @arkascha Dont apologise, he must have deleted it because nobody coded a solution for it. _You can lead a horse to water but you cannot make it THINK_

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am almost convinced Mr. Ed would disagree... But you are probably right ;-)

Comment: @arkascha RiggsFolly Thank you soo many guys It worked like charm

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. Most `sanitize` functions are completely worthless.

Comment: Also, before you go too far down the road of writing your own ORM-like system, you really should evaluate existing ones like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/), or 
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) to see if any are good enough for your needs. This sort of code is brutally taxing to get right, so any help you can get is a huge asset.

Comment: Why did someone delete my last comment. Surely it was not in any way unpleasant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that you do to indicate that a user is logged in is set `$_SESSION['SBUser'] = $user_id;`

So in your registration script just do that as well.

```
<?php 
// new code
session_start();

$name = ((isset($_POST['name']))?sanitize($_POST['name']):'');
$email = ((isset($_POST['email']))?sanitize($_POST['email']):'');
$password = ((isset($_POST['password']))?sanitize($_POST['password']):'');
$confirm = ((isset($_POST['confirm']))?sanitize($_POST['confirm']):'');
$errors = array();
if($_POST){
    $emailQuery =$db->query("SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE email = '$email'");
    $emailCount = mysqli_num_rows($emailQuery);

    if($emailCount != 0){
        $errors[] = 'That email already exists in our database.';
    }

    $required = array('name', 'email', 'password', 'confirm');
    foreach($required as $f){
        if(empty($_POST[$f])){
            $errors[] = 'You must fill out all fields';
            break;
        }
    }
    if(strlen($password) < 6){
        $errors[] = 'Your password must be atleast 6 characterss';
    }
    if($password != $confirm){
        $errors[] = 'Your password do not match';
    }
    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $errors[] = 'You must enter a valid email';
    }
    if(!empty($errors)){
        echo display_errors($errors);
    }else{
        //add user to database
        $hashed = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $db->query("INSERT INTO users1 
                          (full_name,email,password) 
                    values('$name', '$email','$hashed')");

        // new code
        $_SESSION['SBUser'] = $db->insert_id;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Well saves having to see the question for a third time

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble @riggsFolly, First time I didn't quite actually understand so deleted the question to post code again more presentable way,